# Hover to resume Webkit animation work on JSFiddle, but won't work on my website

Tags: html, css

I'm able to run my script fine within JSFiddle, but when I try to run within Chrome or IE11 on my website, there is no response to hovering.  Anybody have any advice? I know I'm missing something obvious here.

It's saved as an HTML webpage when I try to run within my website, and the CSS is (for now) on the same document as the HTML.

```
  #backgroundBox{
z-index:-1;
left:50%;
top:50%;
background-color:#cdcba9;
width:400px;
height:400px;
position:absolute;
margin-left:-200px;
margin-top:-200px;
}

#backgroundBox:hover div{
-webkit-animation-play-state:running; 
animation-play-state:running;}

.ball {
    z-index:1;
    border: 20px solid #356db4;
    border-top: 20px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-left: 20px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-radius: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
    top:-295px;
    left:-20px;
    -moz-animation: spin 3s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: spin 3s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g5zQ8/3/

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a difference check on your page source and Vorenus's page source or run your page source through the W3C validator. I saved it and it works fine locally in Chrome, even when not using a proper HTML5 doctype.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine when I translate it to a standalone file, see:
http://www.saltcollective.com/stuff/bike.html

Is it possible that you're borking the HTML/CSS somehow?

Comment: This is bizarre.  Clearly works fine in your case, but as soon as I copy/paste the source from the site you just posted into Notepad++ and run it in Chrome, it breaks again.  Is it just something I didn't know about Notepad++?  :P

Comment: It could be an encoding issue of some description I guess, but that seems odd to me. Maybe try creating a file in a plaintext editor or in terminal and see if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

I converted the JSFiddle to a single file (http://jsbin.com/fanesihi/1/edit) and it worked fine.

If you are implementing this into a website, and it isn't working than it is one of two things:

1) Incorrect implementation. Perhaps some of the CSS wasn't copied or something of that nature.

2) Other CSS within your site is overriding the animation CSS class.

In order to truly debug the issue, I'd need to see an example of it not working.

As a side note, remember to include non-browser prefixed version of your keyframe animations. Also, your trailing semicolons within the keyframe blocks CAN cause issue strange bugs further down in the stylesheet (just saw that issue on here a couple days ago)...it would be best to remove them:

```
@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes spinoff {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello!  Thanks for the reply!  So are you saying I should remove the semicolons after the "transform:rotate(0deg);}"


So it should look like this?

@-webkit-keyframes spinoff {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
}

I'm working on getting a real world example of the site together.  Just waiting to hear back from 1and1

Comment: Correct. The above code example shows the proper format.